# Why is this unordered list item getting pushed to a new line?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use custom list item bullets.  Everything seems to be fine, except in cases where there's text overflow.  In these cases, the text gets pushed to below the custom bullet.  How can I keep everything on the same line, even with overflow?  I do want to display overflow with break-word, I just don't want it moved.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BZbJE/1/

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
a {
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
li:before {
    content:"• ";
    color:red;
}
li {
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -.7em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the `a` element.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/2TEt7/)

```
a {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also add the same to the pseudo element.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Lkcv2/)

```
li:before {
    content:"• ";
    color:red;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Just a note for anyone else with this problem - for FF only the latter option seems to work, and you can't use both together.

Comment: @SB2055 Thanks for the note. I have no explanation as to why the first option doesn't work in FF. This is odd behavior, and quite possibly a bug.